# Capturing a trait in a struct that is only used in the implementation

Tags: rust, traits

How do you define a `struct` that has a polymorphic struct and trait associated with it, but where the trait does not factor into the `struct` definition, only implementation?

Here the compiler refuses to accept this definition of `Interpreter` since `Evaluator` is unused, yet it is necessary within the implementation:

```
pub trait StateEvaluator<State> {
    fn eval(state: State, buf: &mut [u8]);
}

pub struct Interpreter<State, Evaluator> {
    state: State
}

impl<State: Default, Evaluator: StateEvaluator<State>> Interpreter<State, Evaluator> {
    pub fn new() -> Interpreter<State, Evaluator> {
        Interpreter {
            state: Default::default()
        }
    }

    pub fn eval(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) {
        Evaluator::eval(self.state, buf)
    }
}
```

Removing that from the `struct` causes a mismatch on the `impl` version and a different compiler error about expecting 1 argument and getting 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type parameter `Evaluator` is called a [*phantom type*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type) because it is not used in the type definition. Rust used to allow such code to compile, but a [change earlier this year related to variance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md) outlawed it. Instead, you must use the type parameter.

To retain its phantom nature, you can use a "marker" of sorts called [`PhantomData`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html). This is a special type that is interpreted by the compiler.

Making your code work is easy. Just add a `PhantomData` member that uses your phantom type parameter:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Interpreter<State, Evaluator> {
    state: State,
    _marker: PhantomData<Evaluator>,
}
```

And then tweak the construction slightly:

```
Interpreter {
    state: Default::default(),
    _marker: PhantomData,
}
```

Type inference will fill in the type parameter for `PhantomData` automatically.

Comment: Sort of a missed opportunity there to adopt the `phantom` modifier as suggested in the RFC. That did the trick, though.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of directions you can go:

- Add a [phantom data marker for `Evaluator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html):

  ```rust
  use std::marker;

  pub trait StateEvaluator<State> {
      fn eval(state: State, buf: &mut [u8]);
  }

  pub struct Interpreter<State, Evaluator> {
      state: State,
      evaluator: marker::PhantomData<Evaluator>,
  }

  impl<State: Default + Clone, Evaluator: StateEvaluator<State>> Interpreter<State, Evaluator> {
      pub fn new() -> Interpreter<State, Evaluator> {
          Interpreter {
              state: Default::default(),
              evaluator: marker::PhantomData,
          }
      }

      pub fn eval(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) {
          Evaluator::eval(self.state.clone(), buf)
      }
  }
  ```

  This way the generic type is used in the struct. (Note that I’ve made the executive decision to add the `Clone` bound to `State` so that `eval` can pass a `State` to the `StateEvaluator`; you could also go for it taking `&State` or a `Copy` bound.)
- Shift the `Evaluator` generic from the type to the `eval` function. This is probably not what you want, but as it just might be I’ll mention it.

  ```rust
  pub trait StateEvaluator<State> {
      fn eval(state: State, buf: &mut [u8]);
  }

  pub struct Interpreter<State> {
      state: State,
  }

  impl<State: Default + Clone> Interpreter<State> {
      pub fn new() -> Interpreter<State> {
          Interpreter {
              state: Default::default(),
          }
      }

      pub fn eval<Evaluator: StateEvaluator<State>>(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) {
          Evaluator::eval(self.state.clone(), buf)
      }
  }
  ```